# How to validate objects that were deserialized with Jackson polymorphic deserialization

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, bean-validation

**Given the following request:**

```
/enterprises-api/{{version}}/enterprises?query={"searchType":"FOUNDERSEARCH","maxResult":"61",...}
```

OR

```
/enterprises-api/{{version}}/enterprises?query={"searchType":"NAMEORADDRESSSEARCH","maxResult":"61",...}
```

I have managed to deserialize *query* into either a FounderSearch or NameOrAddressSearch object based on the searchType property.

However, Javax validation is ignored because this isn't a toplevel object. How can I resolve this?

**Top level object:**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "searchType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FounderSearch.class, name = "FOUNDERSEARCH"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NamerOrAddressSearch.class, name = "NAMEORADDRESSSEARCH")
})
public abstract class Query {
    public abstract boolean isFounderSearch();
}
```

**One of the sub-level objects:**

```
@Data
public class FounderSearch extends QueryObject {

    @Min(1) @Max(60)
    private Integer maxResult = 20;
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{11}")
    private String personNumber;
    private List<CodeType> functions;
    private Boolean activeFunctions;

    public boolean isFounderSearch() {
        return true;
    }

    public SearchType getSearchType() {
        return SearchType.FOUNDERSEARCH;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I have the same issue

Comment: I don't remember unfortunately. I don't have access to that source code anymore.

Comment: In my case I worked when I added @field:Valid in property of the supertype declaration. I'm using Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

If you add @Valid annotation on nested objects as well it will work.

something like this, above all the fields that have validation constraints.

@Data
public class FounderSearch extends QueryObject {

```
@Min(1) @Max(60)
@Valid
private Integer maxResult = 20;
@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{11}")
@Valid
private String personNumber;
private List<CodeType> functions;
private Boolean activeFunctions;

public boolean isFounderSearch() {
    return true;
}

public SearchType getSearchType() {
    return SearchType.FOUNDERSEARCH;
}
```

}

Comment: Tell me where, there is no field where I can put it.

Comment: In my case I worked when I added @field:Valid in property of the supertype declaration. I'm using Kotlin